# TimeInterval in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3, xcode8

Hi I need to convert this piece of code in Objective-c to Swift
[image: Objective-C code]
but I'm having problem with Date and TimeInterval objects.
[image: Swift code]
Swift version: 3
Xcode version: 8.0 beta

**EDIT:**
Is this a possible solution?
[image: Possible solution]

**EDIT 2:**
[image]

Comment: you must call `timeIntervalSince` on an instance of `NSDate`, but not on the class `NSDate`. Otherwise, it does not return an `NSTimerInterval` (double) but a `NSDate`. Anyway, I think that XCode must return an error when you call `NSDate.timeIntervalSince(currentDate)` cause it is not the class function.

Comment: can you post an example in code?

Comment: I've posted the code.

Comment: @Hoa There's no error because instance methods in Swift [are curried at static scope](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/). i.e `NSDate.timeIntervalSince` returns a `(Date) -> (Date) -> TimeInterval` – where the first parameter is the `Date` instance to call the function on, and the second parameter is the `Date` parameter for the `timeIntervalSince` function.

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli : you can use directly `NSDate().timeIntervalSince...` and remove `.init` in your edit code

Comment: @originaluser2 : like it return a pointer of an `timeInterval` on a `Date`? So we can call: `let anInterval = timeInterval(self.startDate)`

Comment: @Hoa using NSDate(). instead of currentDate. , Xcode gives me the error i posted in the question

Comment: @Hoa If you got the instance method from the instance directly, i.e `currentDate.timeIntervalSince`, then yes you'd indeed have a reference to `currentDate` via that method. If you got it from the static scope, i.e `Date.timeIntervalSince`, then you would just have a function that could return the instance method, provided you gave it an instance to operate on.

Comment: it gives me the same error

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli What error? Please post your current code by copy and pasting it into the body of the question rather than posting a screenshot, along with the exact error it gives.

Comment: using Date or NSDate it gives me an error, if call the method via instance currentDate the error disappear. I will post up the code with the error

Comment: @AngeloPettinelli Your second line should be `NSDate().timeIntervalSince(startDate as Date)`, just as Hoa has said in his answer. Although I would recommend switching over to `Date` to simplify your code as Altimir says in his answer – unless you need the reference semantics of `NSDate`. Also for future reference please do not use screenshots to show code. Copy and paste your code into the question to allow others to easily replicate it. If you need to show errors, then you can also copy and paste them as text into the question.

Comment: aaaah ok! so it is correct the first update! but instead of NSDate, using just Date in Swift 3 (as is saying the answer under that). Ty all

Comment: or even instead (as @Hoa suggests), removing currentDate variable using the class method

Answer (score 1):

According to my comment, your code must be:

```
private func updateTimer() {
    let currentDate = NSDate()
    let timeInterval = currentDate.timeIntervalSince(self.startDate)
    let timerDate = NSDate(timerIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
}
```

or

```
private func updateTimer() {
    //we don't have to create the variable "currentDate".
    let timeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince(self.startDate)
    let timerDate = NSDate(timerIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
}
```

Comment: perfect I posted it as I edited my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 use Date:

```
private func updateTimer() {
    let currentDate = Date()
    let timeInterval = currentDate.timeIntervalSince(self.startDate)
    let timerDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
}
```